# Modification of email template

Tags: forms, users

I am working on a site where I changed the "email template" email to be sent on registration request to the user. How can I change the "email template" email sent to the site administrators?

I am using Drupal 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's also worth looking at the [Mail Editor](http://drupal.org/project/mail_edit) module. It makes the job of managing email templates easier and in combination with Token gives you more options for customizing emails.

Comment: I check that module there is no potion for us to edit email template which is sent to the Administrators id

Comment: Yes, there is. You need to go to admin/config/system/mail-edit and add the register_pending_approval_admin template. You can then edit it as you like.

Answer (score 2):

Go to admin/config/people/accounts, Under **Emails** click Account Activation and then change as per your requirement. Use html and css for customization. See the below image

[image]

(or)

Use the second option below:

All the emails are being sent from the system and the content is editable as we want. To stylize the emails, use html mail module http://drupal.org/project/htmlmail

This module allows you to theme emails leaving the system as you would theme a normal Drupal site, and replaces the outgoing emails with those HTML versions per your settings.

hope it helps you!!!

Comment: Bala actually i want to edit the email which is sent to administrators id through the system

Comment: That email is also on the same page under another tab.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is pretty old, but if someone got into this issue please take a look at

[User registration notification Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_register_notify)

This will help you out.